# android 10, xamarin Как управлять встроенным медиаплеером с помощью intent?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, android-intent

Есть приложение, которое с помощью Intent может ставить на паузу/продолжать, переключать текущую песню из любого плеера. Код работал на android 9. На 10 ничего не происходит.

```
public class AudioMediaService
{

    private Intent musicIntent;

    public void PauseResume()
    {
        
        if (manager.IsMusicActive)
            pause();
        else
            resume();
    }

    private void pause()
    {
        musicIntent.PutExtra(Intent.ExtraKeyEvent, new KeyEvent(KeyEventActions.Down, Keycode.MediaPause));
        Android.App.Application.Context.SendOrderedBroadcast(musicIntent, null);
        musicIntent.PutExtra(Intent.ExtraKeyEvent, new KeyEvent(KeyEventActions.Up, Keycode.MediaPause));
        Android.App.Application.Context.SendOrderedBroadcast(musicIntent, null);
    }

    private void resume()
    {
        musicIntent.PutExtra(Intent.ExtraKeyEvent, new KeyEvent(KeyEventActions.Down, Keycode.MediaPlay));
        Android.App.Application.Context.SendOrderedBroadcast(musicIntent, null);
        musicIntent.PutExtra(Intent.ExtraKeyEvent, new KeyEvent(KeyEventActions.Up, Keycode.MediaPlay));
        Android.App.Application.Context.SendOrderedBroadcast(musicIntent, null);
    }

    public void Next()
    {
        musicIntent.PutExtra(Intent.ExtraKeyEvent, new KeyEvent(KeyEventActions.Down, Keycode.MediaNext));
        Android.App.Application.Context.SendOrderedBroadcast(musicIntent, null);
        musicIntent.PutExtra(Intent.ExtraKeyEvent, new KeyEvent(KeyEventActions.Up, Keycode.MediaNext));
        Android.App.Application.Context.SendOrderedBroadcast(musicIntent, null);
    }

    public void Previous()
    {
        musicIntent.PutExtra(Intent.ExtraKeyEvent, new KeyEvent(KeyEventActions.Down, Keycode.MediaPrevious));
        Android.App.Application.Context.SendOrderedBroadcast(musicIntent, null);
        musicIntent.PutExtra(Intent.ExtraKeyEvent, new KeyEvent(KeyEventActions.Up, Keycode.MediaPrevious));
        Android.App.Application.Context.SendOrderedBroadcast(musicIntent, null);
    }

    public AudioMediaService()
    {
        musicIntent = new Intent(Intent.ActionMediaButton);
    }
}
```

Может необходимо какое-то дополнительное разрешение или данный способ уже устарел? Есть ли аналогичное решение?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел решение: нужно вместо Intent использовать `Instrumentation`.

```
    private void pause()
    {
        Task.Run(() =>
        {
            Instrumentation inst = new Instrumentation();
            inst.SendKeyDownUpSync(Keycode.MediaPause);
        });
    }

    private void resume()
    {
        Task.Run(() =>
        {
            Instrumentation inst = new Instrumentation();
            inst.SendKeyDownUpSync(Keycode.MediaPlay);
        });
    }
```

Comment: Лучше используйте `Task.Run(() => { ... });` вместо `Thread`, раз уж на то пошло. Хотя вообще не понятно, зачем здесь потоки.

Comment: @aepot Если не использовать, то возникала ошибка. (Java.Lang.RuntimeException: 'This method can not be called from the main application thread')

Comment: А, так это java, ну ладно, просто вы тег C# поставили. Тогда не понятно, при чем тут C#.

Comment: @aepot Нет, это c#. Я пишу на xamarin forms. Но ошибка такая возникает...

Comment: Ну тогда хотя-бы `Task.Run`